# Parsing JSON with SwifyJSON

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, xcode8, swifty-json

Here's the structure of the JSON I am trying to parse. I want to be able to loop through to access the questions.

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "C&Q" : [
    {
      "category" : "Applicant Details",
      "questions" : [
        {
          "compulsory" : true,
          "options" : "Mr.; Mrs.; Miss",
          "input" : "radio",
          "question" : "Title"
        },
        {
          "compulsory" : true,
          "options" : "N\/A",
          "input" : "text",
          "question" : "Surname"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category" : "Identification Documents",
      "questions" : [
        {
          "compulsory" : true,
          "options" : "Passport;Drivers License;Voter ID;NHIS",
          "input" : "radio",
          "question" : "ID TYPE"
        },
        {
          "compulsory" : true,
          "options" : "N\/A",
          "input" : "date",
          "question" : "Date of Issue (YYYY-MM-DD)"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Here's code but I can only access by index. Perhaps someone could help with sample code on how to loop through so that I can access the questions array.

```
let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)

guard let questions = swiftyJsonVar["C&Q"].arrayValue[0]["questions"].arrayObject as? [[String:AnyObject]] else
{
    print("parsing failed")
    return
}
```

This is how I use/plan to use the array which works well with the above parsing.

```
let questionsStructs = questions.map(Questions.init)
self.formsData = questionsStructs
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var questions:[Question] = []
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["C&Q"] {
    for (key,j):(String, JSON) in subJson["questions"] {
        let question = Question(......)
        questions.append(question)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @user1941284 however I could not figure out what the type is for the array questions [Question]. Could you please provide some more clarity?

Comment: Do you want to put all questions together or you want to split them by category?

Comment: I will want to split them by category. Thank you.